# Singleton -- оптимальная реализация

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-одиночка

В [PEP0318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples) приведен такой паттерн одиночки:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class MyClass:
```

Сразу же бросается в глаза некоторая неоптимальность данной каноничной реализации (простите что святотатствую). Так, если это паттерн "одиночка", то зачем нам словарь инстансов (причем сам термин во множественном числе)?

Недолго думая я набросал свой собственный велосипед:

```
def Singleton(f):
    instance = f()
    return lambda : instance

@Singleton
class Some:
   def __init__(self):
        print(str(self.__class__) + " init here.")
```

который точно также прекрасно справляется со своей задачей. Это может быть и неочевидно на первый взгляд, но проверьте и убедитесь:

```
first = Some()
second = Some()
third = Some()

print("first == second ?", first == second)
print("first == third  ?", first == third)
```

Вывод:

```
<class '__main__.Some'> init here.
first == second ? True
first == third  ? True
```

А вопрос будет такой: какие вы видите недостатки в подобной реализации? Может быть я чтото не учел? Заранее благодарю за конструктивные ответы.

---

Upd. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076134/singleton-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-v-2) доработанный вариант синглтона с учетом всех замечаний.

Comment: если я правильно все понял, то оригинальный `Singleton` хранит словарь типа `class`: `instance`. для каждого нового класса хранит его единственный экземпляр, в то время как ваша реализация возвращает для каждого класса просто отдельный экземпляр. по факту - одно и тоже, разными словами, различий в логике или при наследовании я не нашел..

Comment: @finally, спасибо Вам за проведенный анализ.

Comment: самому стало интересно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В реализации из PEP0318 для каждого класса с декоратором @singleton экземпляр будет создан только в тот момент, когда он будет в первый раз запрошен.

В вашей реализации экземпляр создаётся в тот момент, когда в коде встречается определение класса, даже если по факту дальше в коде экземпляр класса никогда явно не создаётся.

Более того, если в одном модуле определено много классов с вашим декоратором, а другой модуль импортирует из первого только один класс, то экземпляры будут созданы сразу для всех.

Это может быть нежелательным поведением по следующим причинам:

1. Инстанцирование экземпляра может занимать много времени, памяти или требовать такие ресурсы, как соединение с базой, открытые файлы, сетевые сокеты и т.п. Лишние экземпляры буду зря тратить эти ресурсы. Кроме того, для программиста, который использует вашу реализацию декоратора может быть вообще сюрпризом, что эти ресурсы оказались заняты. Если он не планировал создавать экземпляры нескольких классов с этим декоратором, то существует вероятность, что он написал свой код так, что эти неожиданные экземпляры вообще будут конфликтовать друг с другом. Отладка всего этого может оказаться для него очень нетривиальной задачей ))
2. Инстанцирование экземпляра может требовать определённых условий. Например, класс может ожидать, что в момент создания экземпляра уже будет существовать подключение к базе данных. Но если инстанцирование происходит не в момент, когда экземпляр явно в первый раз запрошен в коде, а гораздо раньше, то это может стать проблемой.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за развернутый ответ. В общем то да, мой вариант действительно отрабатывает в момент применения (декорирования класса), и все остальное -- уже как следствие из этой особенности. Это легко исправить парой доп. строк кода декоратора но мне подумалось что и такое красивое решение имеет право на жизнь :)

Comment: а что скажете по поводу этого доработанного варианта: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076134/singleton-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-v-2 ?