# Singleton — оптимальная реализация v.2

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton, шаблон-одиночка

Дальнейшее развитие темы оптимальной реализации паттерна 'Синглтон' на Пайтоне, поднятой в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075791/singleton-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Учел недостаток предыдущего решения, освещенный в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1075892/361504).

Предлагаю такую оптимальную реализацию паттерна Синглтон:

```
def Singleton(cls, instances={}):
    if cls not in instances:
        instances[cls] = cls()
    return lambda : instances[cls]

@Singleton
class MyClass
...
```

Вопрос остается прежний:
Какие вы видите недостатки в подобной реализации? 
Заранее благодарю за конструктивные ответы.

Comment: Изменяемые значения в качестве аргументов по-умолчанию - это очень грубая ошибка и источник ужаснейших багов, которые отловить будет сложно. Я про `instance=[]`. Всякий раз, когда будете добавлять что-нибудь в `instance`, при следующем вызове аргумент по-умолчанию будет уже не пустой список - он изменится.

Comment: @mrEvgenX
В данном случае это не баг а фича :) Именно указанная Вами особенность здесь и используется.

Comment: Понял. Субъективно. По мне - это аналогично сжиганию дома, чтоб оптимально погреться. Я бы не играл с этим. Ровно как и с синглтонами, из всех паттернов вокруг него больше всего дискуссий антипаттерн это или паттерн. Нужно тщательное исследование конкретной ситуации, чтоб применять его.

Comment: Попробуйте два разных класса завернуть в ваш декоратор. И создайте экземпляры.

Comment: @mrEvgenX вопрос не о целесообразности применения Синглтона как такового. Субъективно я также могу в чемто согласиться с Вами.

Comment: Понял, что не про целесообразность, вырвалось просто:) Ну главный недостаток - мутабельные аргументы по-умолчанию. Нормальный линтер вас отчитает. Другое дело, что ничего не работает. В списке instance будет только один первый попавшийся декорированный класс. Сделайте то, что @Avernial говорит. Я попробовал. Создаю MyClass2 с декоратором, а потом создаю экземпляр, а переменная получается типа MyClass. Или именно это тоже ожидалось?

Comment: @mrEvgenX да я понял свою ошибку. Спасибо

Comment: @Avernial спасибо, понял свою ошибку. Сейчас немного подправлю.

Comment: В итоге придете к PEP0318)

Comment: @Avernial ну почти. С использованием ламбды у меня получилось сделать замыкание немного компактнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сравнить с реализацией через базовый класс:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
            class_._instance = object.__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instance

class B(Singleton, А):
    pass
```

О недостатках же можно говорить сравнивая с чем-то.